# android-how to stop services in android

Tags: android, android-service

I want to stop the service when I come to the activity . This is my activity code :

```
stopService(new Intent(this, Services_chat.class));
```

on call this on the mainactivity and in the oncreate method . so I certainly called .

this is my service code:

```
public class Services_chat extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.v("this","caa");

            }
        }, 0, 1000);//put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

As you can seen I log and run this code every second , so after running my app and it calls for stopping service , it doesn't stop and it still runs .

How can I stop this service ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

write this method in *Services_chat* class.

```
@Override
public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    timer.cancel();
    task.cancel();
    return super.stopService(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding service via `onBind()` from `MainActivity` then call `unBindService()` method to stop service

If you are starting service via `startService()` from `MainActivity` then call `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`

Android system will try to stop service as soon as possible upon `stop` request from application

**UPDATE :**

Add code to stop timer in `onDestroy()` like :

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mTimer.cancel();
}
```

Make object of `Timer` instead of using **Annonymous class Timer** :

in `onStartCommand()` :

```
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.v("this","caa");

            }
        },0,1000);
```

Comment: I'm not using onBind , I'm using startService() as you can see in my code , also I've stopService() on my code in activity , I've tried stopSelf()  , not worked

Comment: Using `stopService` -- your service is already stopped.. just timer is running so you are Log in logcat.. but service is stopped..